# Is it possible that the universe is not expanding faster than the speed of light?

Tags: spacetime, speed-of-light, universe, space-expansion, faster-than-light

What if the speed of light increases proportionately to the expansion of space? Is it possible that light traveling in the medium of space gets to travel faster if the medium is expanding? An analogy is to put a drop of floating dye into water. If you drag your finger across the drop it stretches across the water where your finger travels. The dye would be light and your finger would be the simulation of the expansion of space. Is there anyway that this could be possible?

Comment: This site answers questions about mainstream physics, not personal theories. In mainstream cosmology, the speed of light is constant.

Comment: You are correct. This is exactly how light propagates in the expanding space. Roughtly speaking, the remote speed of light is a sum of the local speed of light and the speed of the space expansion in that place relative to us. I say, "roughly", because measuring speed remotely is not straightforward.

Comment: @G.Smith Are you sure, Sir? Only the local speed of light is constant. The OP is asking about the remote speed of light and his description appears to be in compliance with General Relativity.

Comment: @safesphere, I continue to be alarmed at the number of times contributors here presume to have the standing to speak for the OP.  Perhaps the OP *is* asking about the "remote speed of light" (whatever that may mean), and I do believe you're convicted that this is what the OP is asking about, but only the OP has the standing to state that is what, *in fact*, is being asked about.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri The "*stretches across*" and "*travels*" references are hardly local, but you are welcome to interpret the question per your understanding or inquire the OP.

Comment: @safesphere The “remote speed of light” is such an uncommon concept that I cannot find a single legitimate reference to it by googling. The top hit is for a Bluetooth remote control.

Comment: @G.Smith A more common term is "global" as opposed to "local". However, the meaning of "global" is incorrect. For example, in the view of a remote observer, the speed of light at a very particular point near a black hole is lower due to the time dilation there. In this case the observed speed of light is slower than the local speed of ligh that of course is always constant. However, the "global" reference is incorrect in this case, because we are are not describing the speed of light everywhere globally, but only at a very particular **remote** location.

Comment: I'm confused now. Is it possible or impossible? I am not trained in physics or cosmology or the like and I have no clue whether what I'm asking is mainstream or non-mainstream physics. I just watch some random videos about space and science on YouTube once in a while. So the fact that this question is flagged means that mainstream physics doesn't currently support the idea that light can travel at different velocities depending on whether the space medium is expanding? And yes, Alfred Centauri, safesphere is correctly speaking what I am trying to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Well that depends as researchers say that the the universes expansion is accelerating because of dark energy that increases spaces at various points, it is hard to determine what the acceleration rate is but it is noted in 1998 by researchers of the acceleration.

Comment: "*that depends as researchers say that the the universes expansion is accelerating because of dark energy that increases spaces at various points*" - You seem to confuse expansion with acceleration. The answer doesn't depend on the acceleration and the expansion is not caused by dark energy.

Comment: The dark energy does have an effect on the expansion rate of the universe though, https://science.nasa.gov/astrophysics/focus-areas/what-is-dark-energy

Comment: Dark energy defines the acceleration of the expansion in the FLRW model. However, the answer to this question does not depend on the existence of dark energy or even on the type of the cosmological model. As long as space expands, even if there is no dark energy, the speed of expansion adds to the speed of light.